# AIMD TCP Protocol

Tags: tcp, protocols

Consider a long flow being transmitted in 1 kB packets by a transport protocol that (only) uses AIMD to control the window size. Initially, the window size is 10 kB. Every time the window opens to 20 kB, the last packet in the window is dropped, which is detected exactly after one round-trip time, and re transmitted. How many packets are sent up to and including the first packet that is dropped?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 165 packets 10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20=165 as
Window will add one pkt each time till it gets a massage of dropping a pkt.